# Does adding text "I am not a lawyer" or equivalent, on the internet in general, do anything in legal terms?

Tags: international, unlicensed-practice

There's [this question here about US specifically](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/683/usa-is-i-am-not-a-lawyer-disclaimer-generally-necessary), but I'm interested to know if, in general, on any site on the internet, whichever jurisdiction its content may be hosted in, does adding "I am not a lawyer" to your advice protect you from any potential liability?

I know people use it mostly to prevent possible misunderstanding and interpreting as professional advice. Some claim though that they "heard somewhere" that they could get in trouble should things involve actual lawyers. Does such a statement as "I am not a lawyer" on StackExchange, Reddit, Quora, Yahoo answers or another site/community with a multinational audience and users from all sorts of jurisdictions have any legal meaning?

Comment: I don't think you're going to get a better answer than the one on the linked question.  The same general legal principles of liability apply "on the internet in general."  I would close this as a duplicate.

Comment: @feetwet I would start my comment with "welcome to StackExchange" but you're a mod so heh. The fact that the answer would be essentially same doesn't mean that the questions are identical and therefore may be closed as such. The other one is asking about US specifically, and I'm asking specifically about the rest of the world also. I don't know US law, maybe that answer only applies to US.

Comment: This is a tricky issue particular to [Law.se] – ref [meta discussions on jurisdiction](http://meta.law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jurisdiction).  The evolving convention seems to be that even if the question is specifically posed for a jurisdiction, answers for others are always helpful.  Especially because there is no real "international jurisdiction."  So, for example, on this question someone *could* give you a vague general answer, or [an excellent answer based in real laws particular to one or more specific jurisdictions](http://law.stackexchange.com/a/699/10).